# Create GUI UI at GameObject position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to create a GUI UI at the position of a GameObject, specifically this example menu:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html

I've tried this:

```
new Rect (playerPosX, playerPosY, 100, 90)
```

as the first argument using gameObject.transform.position.x and y but the GUI is top-left based.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want it based on the top-left? You'll need to use 0,0 for the first 2 parameters instead of `playerPosX, playerPosY`

Comment: I think he wants the same menu, but not on the top-left corner. He wants it to be dynamic, I'd say....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorldToScreenPoint` will do the trick.
[Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)

```
var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(GameObject.Find("NameOfObject").transform.position);
    Rect d = new Rect(Screen.width - pos.x, Screen.height - pos.y, 400, 400);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all convert the player position which is in world coordinate system (Cartesian coordinate system) into screen co-ordinate space which you have mentioned top-left based use

```
Vecto3 temp = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(playerPosition);
```

you can then use only x and y component of temp (because of top-left position).

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding what you are looking for is not **GUI** its [text mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html). GUI will stick with your (x,y) screen position but the [text mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextMesh.html) is what you can display anywhere in the scene near to your gameobject.